# Find and replace text portion of html element that may contain children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I am extracting some html from a wysiwyg editor and need to parse and replace the text portion.  For example, I might be given html like so:

```
<span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 50.4px;">
    first text I want to replace
    <span style="font-size: 11px;"><i><b>hello world</b></i></span>
    second text I want to replace
    <span style="font-size: 15px;"><i><b>foo bar</b></i></span>
    third text I want to replace
</span>
```

Let's say I wanted to replace the text portion of the parent span and leave the children elements alone.  For example, let's say I wanted to convert the html into this:

```
<span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 50.4px;">
    I replaced my first text
    <span style="font-size: 11px;"><i><b>hello world</b></i></span>
    I replaced my second text
    <span style="font-size: 15px;"><i><b>foo bar</b></i></span>
    I replaced my third text
</span>
```

The value of the strings before replacement and after replacement is not relevant in this question.  I just want to know how I could possible located and replace those strings.

The closest thing I could find online was this nifty trick with jQuery:

```
$("#span-selector").clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

However, this will extract all text from the parent, with no way of being able to replace a modified string in its place.  How could I use javascript/jQuery to find `first text I want to replace` and replace it with `I replaced my first text`

Does anybody think this is possible?  Keep in mind I am getting the html directly from an editor, so its possible a user would enter in some characters that appear like html.  So I don't know if parsing the html manually looking for '<' and '>' would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  get all the children of an element using `.contents()` then use `.eq()` to get the element at the specified index and finally replace the elemnt with `.replaceWith()`

```js
function replaceText() {
  $('#parent').contents().eq(0).replaceWith('<h3>Replaced with HTML</h3>');
  $('#parent').contents().eq(2).replaceWith('replaced 2');
  $('#parent').contents().eq(4).replaceWith('replaced 3');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parent" style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 50.4px;">
    my first text
    <span style="font-size: 11px;"><i><b>hello world</b></i></span>
    my second text
    <span style="font-size: 15px;"><i><b>foo bar</b></i></span>
    my third text
</span>
<button onclick="replaceText()" >Replace</button>
```

Comment: Nice, but it won't work if the user includes their own html will it?

Comment: This is just what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do this alternatively.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/bb5fc2cd381f824153d3b982afb4b1a9)

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</i>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <br><br>
  
  <h1><span>My Span Content</span></h1>
  
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <br><br>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".container" )
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3
    }).each(function(i, a) {
      if (0 === i) { // use suitable condition, in this case, 1st
          $(this).replaceWith('<p>my new content.</p>');
      }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

For future reference, you can do this in plain JS DOM too. Here is the code that will replace your text nodes with 'replaced'

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].childNodes.forEach((node)=>{
  node.data='replaced';
})
```